# Can't set a cookie to expire more than a week away

Tags: javascript, cookies

Both of these approaches end up in a max-age/expiry only 7 days in the future.

```
document.cookie = "testCookie=value; max-age=999999999";
document.cookie = "testCookie=value; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT";
```

I've also tried different values with both approaches and various cookie libraries to no joy.

Comment: It's not JavaScript issue only. When I've tried setting "year" cookie from PHP got age of ~6 months. Noticed that with Brave browser only. Well, I rarely use cookie older than 7 days so cheked this for curiosity only.

Comment: Apparently [safari will be implementing this too](https://webkit.org/blog/8613/intelligent-tracking-prevention-2-1/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out this is intended behaviour in the Brave browser. See [#3443](https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/3443) for more info

Answer (score 1):

In new versions of browsers such as Chrome, a maximum limit of 400 days was set for the age of cookies.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).